# Is there a way to collapse groups of procedures?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a block of related sub routines I would like to "group" together within class to make navigating a littel easier.  When I say group, I mean achieve the same functionality of being able collapse and expand a block of code as would with single procedure or class.  Two alternative ways I can think to accomplish this is either use a partial class for those procedures or use namespace.  **I just wanted to see if VS for VB.Net had another way to be able group and collapse blocks of procedures.  Thanks.**

Comment: `#Region`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd032a17%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VS 2005 at least you can use:

```
#Region "NameOfRegion"
    ' Methods go here
#End Region
```

That will allow you to collapse the region just like any other block of code within VS.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `region` directive:

```
 #region Some Idenfifier

 ... Code ...

 #endregion
```

You can then collapse or expand the entire region to show the code contained.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is how regions are declared in C#. Note the lower-case 'r' and the lack quotes around the region identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a region

```
#Region "MathFunctions"
    ' Insert code for the Math functions here.
#End Region
```

[Region information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd032a17%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)